# Disadvantages of having different consumers subscribed to different topics in same consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What are the disadvantages of having different consumers subscribed to different topics in same consumer group with same group id?

If a new consumer joins the above group, is there any effect to other consumers of the group subscribed to different topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a new consumer joins the same group, then the group will rebalance, causing all consumers to stop (potentially mid-processing of records), then restart.

Otherwise, there is no disadvantage as long as all consumer instance have very similar processing logic, or otherwise filter by the topic name by which they want to process.